# UPDATE a mysql table to assign the column value proportionally

Tags: mysql, sql, updates

I have a table with a `category` column as

```
category enum('A', 'B', 'C'),
```

How can I `UPDATE` the entire table to assign `A` to 1/3 of rows, `B` to 1/3 of rows, and `C` to 1/3 of rows (in no particular order)?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably it's a one time thing here is one way to do it:

```
UPDATE table1 SET category = 'A' WHERE category IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT X;
UPDATE table1 SET category = 'B' WHERE category IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT X;
UPDATE table1 SET category = 'C' WHERE category IS NULL;
```

where X is a 1/3 of total rows in your table

```
SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(*) / 3) x FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps randomly assign?  Assumes that you have sufficient rows that resulting distribution will be uniform.

```
CASE ROUND(RAND() * 2,0)
   WHEN 0 then 'A'
   WHEN 1 then 'B'
   WHEN 2 then 'C'
END CASE as Result
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option for doing this in a single statement without having to know your record count beforehand:

```
   UPDATE table, (select @s:=0) as s 
   SET category = 
       CASE 
           WHEN MOD(@s:=@s+1, 3)=1 THEN 'A' 
           WHEN MOD(@s, 3)=2 THEN 'B' 
           ELSE 'C' 
           END;
```

Using a variable to make a row number we can then check it's value using `mod()` to give it one of three values. If you have an autoincrement field on your table that is sequential and there are no deleted rows, then you could use that instead of the variable.